# WCF Service in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 Project

Tags: web-services, wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I cannot seem to access my WCF Service from Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 application.

I am able to add a service reference, like for example in a console applications, but the following code does not work

```
ServiceReference1.MojaSmetkaWcfClient client = new MojaSmetkaWcfClient();
var result = client.GetData(0);
```

It says 'Cannot resolve symbol ServiceReference1'.
This works in a console app project. How can I connect to the WCF service. If it is not possible, are there any alternatives similar to WCF? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by updating my VS2013 to Update 5 (maybe that didn't help solving the problem) and doing the following:

1. Right click on the service reference
2. Configure service reference
3. Uncheck 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies'